# Best Practise for New Client boards

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I've created some 'Master Template' Boards with Cards for different aspects of Client work

I had thought to copy the Cards to different Client Boards as required, but there doesn't seem to be way to do this - Move 'Yes' Copy 'No'.

Any ideas on how to achieve this - or if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy complete lists from the menu (list actions), but the cards only have `move` default in the menu.

But you *can* open them, and then you have, on the right, the `More` link. There you'll find `copy` for cards.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a board and all of its cards (optional) do the following:

1. With a board open, click on the Trello Logo on the left of the board name.
2. From the drop down menu, select "COPY BOARD"
3. Check or Uncheck the box marked "KEEP CARDS" as need be.
4. You new board should then be open.

Comment: Thanks - The Boards are fine. It's the Cards within the boards